# Device rotation causes the current tab to be reset

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a **Xamarin** app that has an Activity with several tabs (each with a fragment).

When I rotate the device, the selected tab always reverts to the first one.

Is this normal?

Should I be storing which tab is selected during `onSaveInstanceState()` and selecting it during `onCreate()`?

Comment: Activity is destroyed during rotation so you should remember your tabs. Some controls save their state during rotation when they have id assigned (like EditText). I am not sure if this applies in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that on a configuration change like the rotation of the screen the current activity gets destroyed and recreated. In case of a tab activity this includes the tab activity itself and also the activities of each tab.

So when it got recreated it simply shows the first tab as it has no other information.

To fix this you can override [`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) of you tab activity and return the current selected tab. In the on onCreate of the tab activity you then call [`getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) which returns the object you returned in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). If the object is null, you know that there was no orientation change so you simply select the first tab, if it isn't null then there was a screen rotation and you can use the returned value to decide which tab was selected before and set it again.